# My modal div does not close

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

[image]

So, this is where I will be displaying the inventory to the user. I got some CSS code from the internet and I modified it to my needs. Although it does open, it does not close.

Below are the code snippets of what makes it work:

#### HTML

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
            <div>
                <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.modalDialog{
            position: fixed;
            font-family: sans;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            z-index: 99999;
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
            -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
            transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
            pointer-events: none;
        }       
        .modalDialog:target{
            opacity: 1;
            pointer-events: visible;
        }
        .modalDialog > div {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            position: relative;
            margin: 10% auto;
            padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background: #fff;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        }
        .close {
            background: #606061;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            line-height: 25px;
            position: absolute;
            right: -12px;
            text-align: center;
            top: -10px;
            width: 24px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
            -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
            -moz-border-radius: 12px;
            border-radius: 12px;
            -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        }
        .close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

#### JavaScript

```
switch(where){
                case "north":
                    if(startingPos>=3){
                        startingPos -= 3;
                        status.innerHTML = messages[startingPos];
                        img.setAttribute("src",images[startingPos]);
                    }else{
                        status.innerHTML = blockedPathMsg[startingPos];
                    }
                    break;
                case "east":
                    if(startingPos%3!=2){
                        startingPos += 1;
                        status.innerHTML = messages[startingPos];
                        img.setAttribute("src",images[startingPos]);
                    }else{
                        status.innerHTML = blockedPathMsg[startingPos];
                    }
                    break;
                case "west":
                    if(startingPos%3!=0){
                        startingPos -= 1;
                        status.innerHTML = messages[startingPos];
                        img.setAttribute("src",images[startingPos]);
                    }else{
                        status.innerHTML = blockedPathMsg[startingPos];
                    }
                    break;
                case "south":
                    if(startingPos<6){
                        startingPos += 3;
                        status.innerHTML = messages[startingPos];
                        img.setAttribute("src",images[startingPos]);
                    }else{
                        status.innerHTML = blockedPathMsg[startingPos];
                    }
                    break;
                case "inventory":
                    var openModal = document.querySelector("#openModal");
                    openModal.style.opacity="1";
                    break;
                default:
                    status.innerHTML = "I do not know that";
            }
```

**What is going wrong? Why does it not work?**

Comment: I don't see `.close` in your JavaScript anywhere...

Answer (score 3):

You have to do something when the close button is clicked:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var close_btns = document.querySelectorAll("#openModal a.close");
    for (var i = 0; i < close_btns.length; i++) {
        close_btns[i].onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById("openModal").style.display = "none";
        };
    }
};
```

It's probably overkill to use `querySelectorAll` over `querySelector`, but I didn't want to assume there was always only 1 `.close` element.

And it could definitely be improved/expanded to find all `.close` elements inside of a `.modalDialog` element, and when clicked, hide their `.modalDialog` container. I didn't feel it was necessary to show because not enough information was provided.

And of course, I'd use `addEventListener`/`attachEvent` instead of setting the `onclick` property.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener

If these modals are dynamically added (or the `.close` elements are dynamically added), you either need to bind their events immediately after being added, or using event delegation. You should determine the closest containing, stable element, and use that (`container`, in the following).

```
window.onload = function () {
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    container.onclick = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
        if (~(" " + target.className + " ").indexOf(" close ")) {
            // Your code to hide the parent modal
        }
    };
};
```

And a way to get the closest parent modal container without needing to hardcode in an `id` is:

```
var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
var pNode = target.parentNode;
while (pNode) {
    if (~(" " + target.parentNode.className + " ").indexOf(" modalDialog ")) {
        pNode.style.display = "none";
        break;
    }
    pNode = pNode.parentNode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where does it close the window in the JS? I see the opacity being set to 1 under case "inventory", but not seeing it being set back to 0 anywhere. Perhaps you are missing that part of the js code, like a click event for the close button. In jQuery it'd be something like:

```
$("#close").live("click").closest("#openModal").css("opacity", "0")
```